# Problem with completion in TexMaker on Elementary OS

Tags: texmaker, linux, auto-completion

I have a problem with Texmaker on my OS (Elementary OS - Luna, with kernel is Ubuntu 12.04). When I type a few words of the command (for example, the word `\begin{document}`), it doesn't appear in the list of possible commands as usual. Instead, it waits until I type the full of the word or whenever I make the backspace some letters.

Surely, that's no the way the Texmaker autocompletion feature is supposed to work... What am I missing?

Note: I have this problem with both TexMaker installed from software manager (version 3.2) and downloaded from the source (version 4.1).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you Check `Configure Texmaker`-->`Editor`-->`Completion` to have auto complete entries appear ?

Comment: yes, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It's because of my input method. I use the `ibus-unikey` (an input method to type Vietnamese). When I quit ibus, everything comes back to normal in Texmaker. The new problem is that how I can use both ibus and Texmaker.

Comment: You probably should add the detail to your question, rather than an answer.

Comment: If that, this is not a question?